# HTML -> PDF rendering issues

Tags: java, html, pdf

I'm generating pdfs from HTML pages with an application. Sometimes, the pdf is formatted correctly (with styles); other times, it lacks style elements.

In the log file I can see the "Error in rendering".

We are using HTML tags and using string buffer we are converting html tag to pdf file. Not sure why we are getting this missing format issues while generating the pdf file.

Comment: What application are you using to generate pdfs from your HTML pages? Or are you _writing_ an application that converts HTML to PDF? Nobody can guess at what _Error in rendering_ could be without _much_ more information in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So sometimes the `CSS` file (style) does convert with the `HTML` file, and sometimes the `CSS` doesn't convert with the `HTML` file.

I'm guessing that you use an external `CSS` file. If I were you, I would try to type your `CSS` code inside your `HTML` file, under the header element, like this:

```
<style>
  body {background-color:#fff}
  h1 {color:#eee}
</style>
```

Comment: I am using YaHP-Converter

Comment: @gyanendrasingh and you use an external CSS file to style your HTML file you want to convert?

Comment: Yes..We used an external CSS file to style the HTML file.